# Why does ax ≤ b mean ay ≤ b?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-explanation

My proof homework states:

As per A set C of real numbers is convex if and only if for all elements in
x, y ∈ C and for every real numbers t with 0 ≤ t ≤ 1, tx + (1 − t)y ∈ C. Suppose
a, b ∈ R. Show that the set C = {x ∈ R | ax ≤ b} is convex.

For the solution, it states: "Thus we are given ax ≤ b and ay ≤ b."

I don't know if I missed the axiom on this, but I can't find the proof online as to why this is. Can someone help?

Comment: Presumably the proof is verifying the definition of convexity for $C$, which would start with taking two elements $x$ and $y$ in $C$. Using the definition of $C$, what does this tell you about $y$?

Answer (score 2):

Take $x,y\in C$. Then $ax\leq b$ and $ay\leq b$. Thus for each $t\in[0,1]$,
$$a(tx+(1-t)y) = tax + (1-t)ay \leq tb + (1-t)b = b.$$